# Why is the \endcsname not found in the following code

Tags: macros, foreach

This is a precursor to my real question.  But for whatever reason, when I tried reducing my code for something to post here, I got more errors.  In particular, the following code gives me an error with the `\endcsname` in the `\foreach` loop.  While the loop doesn't do anything like what I want it to, in my original code it actually compiled.  Now in this snippet I get an error message about a missing `\endcsname`.  Could someone please point out what I'm obviously overlooking?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\def\ae@set@main#1:#2\@nil{%%
  \expandafter\def\csname ae@slogan@#1/main\endcsname{#2}}
\def\slogan{\@ifstar{\set@slogan}{\get@slogan}}

\def\set@slogan#1#2{\ae@set@#1.0.0.0:#2\@nil}
\def\ae@set@#1.#2.#3.#4:#5\@nil{%%
  \expandafter\def\csname ae@slogan@#1@max\endcsname{#2}%%'0
  \expandafter\def\csname ae@slogan@#1.#2\endcsname{#5}}

\newif\if@iterate@through@subslogans
\def\get@slogan#1{%%
  \@ae@sep#1.0.0\@nil
  \ifnum\ae@second>0\relax
    \expandafter\ae@get@\ae@first.0.0.0\@nil
    :\hspace{0.5em}%%'
  \else
    \xdef\aemax{\csname ae@slogan@\ae@first @max\endcsname}%%
    \typeout{====> MAX=\aemax}%%'
    \ifnum\aemax>0\relax
      \@iterate@through@subsloganstrue
    \fi
  \fi
  \ae@get@#1.0.0.0\@nil
  \if@iterate@through@subslogans
    \expandafter\@iterate@subslogans
  \fi
  \@iterate@through@subslogansfalse
}
\def\ae@get@#1.#2.#3.#4\@nil{%%
  \csname ae@slogan@#1.#2\endcsname}

\def\@iterate@subslogans{%%
    \edef\ae@list{}
      \foreach \myx in {1,2,...,\aemax}
      {\typeout{==> (\myx|\ae@first) \csname ae@slogan@\ae@first.\myx \endcsname}%%' :\ae@list   
       }
    \begin{enumerate}\item
      \ae@list
    \end{enumerate}
}

\def\aeitem{\item}
\def\@ae@sep#1.#2.#3\@nil{%%
  \def\ae@first{#1}%%
  \def\ae@second{#2}}

%% define slogans
\slogan*{1}{First of all train in the preliminaries}
\slogan*{1.1}{Arithmetic\rule{1em}{2pt}}
\slogan*{1.2}{Algebra}
\slogan*{1.3}{Geometry}

\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \slogan{1}

  \slogan{1.2}

\end{document}
```

The error message

```
====> MAX=3
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.65   \slogan{1}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` will robustify a number of fragile LaTeX commands, including `\rule`.  It, too, will fix your code, for the reasons that David cites in his answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\rule` is a fragile command so you can not use it in a `\write` without `\protect`.

```
\slogan*{1.1}{Arithmetic \protect\rule{1em}{2pt}}
```

Comment: Argh.  I knew I was overlooking something.  Stay tuned for my real question because it's this same issue, I think, popping up all over again, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to get even the slightest idea what your code is supposed to do, however, putting `\tracingmacros=1` before `\slogan{1}` shows the following:

```
\ae@set@ #1.#2.#3.#4:#5\@nil ->\expandafter \def \csname ae@slogan@#1@max\endcs
name {#2}\expandafter \def \csname ae@slogan@#1.#2\endcsname {#5}
#1<-\def 
#2<-0
#3<-0
#4<-0
#5<-\reserved@b 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.65   \slogan{1}
```

Since `#1` is `\def` which is not expandable, it can't be used inside `\csname...\endcsname`.

Comment: That's where I was getting stuck.  There's no `\def` there to complain about.

Comment: @A.Ellett the `\def` is random fallout from inappropriate expansion of the `\@ifnextchar` in the optional argument handling for `\rule` which doesn't work in a `\write`

Comment: My code is supposed to define a series of *slogans* when called as `\slogan*{<number>}{<content>}`.  The code should then present the slogan when called as `\slogan{<number>}`.  Some slogans have *subslogans* affiliated with them.  When calling the *master* slogan, I was thinking it would be nice to print a list of the subslogans too.  It seems, via @DavidCarlisle 's comments and answer, that it isn't in how I'm defining the slogans but in the combination of `\typeout`s that expansion issues are getting confounded.

Answer (score 1):

I actually need an alternative to @davidcarlisle 's answer because I cannot rely upon the content passed to `\typeout` having fragile commands appropriately `\protect`ed.  Here's a solution which also works by making a call to `\detokenize`:

Instead of calling

```
  \foreach \myx in {1,2,...,\aemax}
  {\typeout{==> (\myx|\ae@first) \csname ae@slogan@\ae@first.\myx \endcsname}%%' :\ae@list   
   }
```

I could instead call

```
  \foreach \myx in {1,2,...,\aemax}
  {\typeout{==> (\myx|\ae@first) \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname ae@slogan@\ae@first.\myx \endcsname}%%' :\ae@list   
   }}
```

Nevertheless, many thanks to David because I hadn't been thinking about issues with `\typeout{...}`.